# Having trouble formatting a date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a datepicker on my site. When you select a date, it displays as dd/mm/yyyy

In order to search the date, the mysql db has to be similar to it

But it looks like yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s which I cant search for

**Edit**
I also wanted to search between two dates but was having difficulty since the two formats were different

My question was, how would I format my search function to find a similarity from the datepicker and the mysql datetime?

Here's what I have so far (date_avialable is the column name)

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_v WHERE Currency='$currency' AND rout_to='$sto' AND

rout_from='$sfrom' AND DATE_FORMAT(date_avialable,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$sfromda' AND 'stoda' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error()) ;
while ( $runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

I wanted to do something like this

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

But didn't know how to call that into the db

Comment: you already got it there.. $phpdate = $runrow['date_available'];

Comment: But the while clause happens after the query. i wanted to format the date before the while. since the search results display right after the close

Comment: Mariee is it a new project, or you already have some (larger) data in it?

Comment: there's more data, but there's nothing that would help format the date. would i need to create a different script and call on it instead? or would that just further the complications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your specification in question are correct try (to change) this in your code..

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_avialable,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

or separate your PICKER date to strings shown bellow on the left and do this

```
AND ($calendarday) = date_format(from_unixtime(date_avialable),'%d')
AND ($calendarmonth) = date_format(from_unixtime(date_avialable),'%m')
AND ($calendaryear) = date_format(from_unixtime(date_avialable),'%Y')
```

If that aint gonna work, please go to phpmyadmin, and try to tell us what is the format of date in your "date_avialable" row. Is it a unix timestamp or d-m-Y or similar..

Comment: nothing displayed. maybe is the between clause thats messing things up?

Comment: its just a datetimestamp that looks like this 2012-03-29 12:00:00

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the fact that `date_avialable` should be `date_available`.